# Why Chrome / Brave does not render background-image of a div over a certain width? How to fix?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a generated image that is over 16000 x1 pixels in size. I would like these to be repeated vertically, so as to create a grid. I set that image (base64 data url) as the background-image of a div.

For an image 16226px wide, it works great. For one 16958px, chrome / brave renders a white background.

See the repro below:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#div1 {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 16226px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAP2IAAAABCAYAAACeV8QgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAABltJREFUeF7tXcl220gMpH4gcx75GM7/f1CYY5Rz8gOaR8WOtXABGluhCV+NpVBVZBpqxz5N03Qdx/E0ZPiaUV4zAM2NcfbE+XzOPYQBejX7qRUyGHKl5OVyGdA9IaZVXMBPD1knnUFnT2T5t0NnYhnrR8hOdZ6QCBJlKE5fTqyEi53czJ4AodBQnZjSmT3hyhjXgMx4Zrjp6DJPIE0ipamnWWRc1C4q46/H7Ay76DLvHx+zYX2I1cPb5raL/jeevD4f7IEzrXeDJheatWTniXV25BjlFbS0s6uDOeOuJ0Bgg8Cws4dLZRqLu55wwRrXhMZSHD5uZ415HjyxUlCjz+tsNlW5HFb8MwOnYZq+1b1oAmN4PkF5d9EEQqaD+Md5me5FMShufGIb0yJmhj5jhvK40FwFj0qRF6toVoXyhOZgEQ9YJz2XPFHSxIm7zr2fKlDviTgp/nRWob2hSEOKJVXp7kXB+LPUxr72Mpnwu2h5wN4aTx10dtEn4bR11K7nznKuhnWeyKXXIlrlZybME8pzRCirM4JOFc35wzxBGAKPLQLoDkK270X5qjxm8PM7oDT9COl20fSM4w+guovCvRbgAOEbYhjqXtRVJWSPfmJDPmN+yoXMpaupXJrBeWJVfmNfMMozQl001G4C5wntAf/W611JPeK8PVHKtGhHYI0QQu2sv4sqgtO5vKZSYRSnyccdRKOycwfVXbSVVcP5WiHp5q0PiDi6zr2oLoNVLZYB7/NE7LQ5um++OxxeLJiecBh8zx4AEPYgWn0f0xNW027XVbeBekEfXrrxRFL+zVQW8KG+iwqwcPmRtbrP5lXiRef7hP7y8zKc/63frcz1I0J8qzf3sKPtolZz7vGw9v0lPGgYW2dby+vmPKFNzIHruXoC+gGDBid0KG82V08IJuNN1dDo1qC9S3vmB1Z5hYapF1NePRGHbatzHCotpvPUue2ib2f238+x0cimKoIayJM9Y4O4FzUSjaoDNc4IJlxZtF3Uh6BywRbPu2fMrujrahizx2eavl/H8etMVn0tMfBgo2N4avc9UU45HAPliQjJsd836veiERRXT1UG5r3j7Xz2+vMdqtgzFYN5MxCA7O6ihBrN2ljWZoGCAcJCbRVMOk9IKOPmcuOtiAGq600JyRNA/BQUewbaPCFxriS3kY+Xll4YvPo08rKS1uYJOQYuW9x4OUJGBWhwjDneQ//uop3NxWdCIUPKoTRfYYS5RM/3okoUHa7M7i7aAyOC54+fys9Ao3j+t+PXlzcRrPkvAT9coolpeakowpc+WcwngYG7Hv/8/jGM41j3ogTajhIStXcchV/bOW1eIFiesJnRVpf+qkffi5YLgBh4h3LoXRRIDuu3zeuo68MfYhe1Jryz+ljnCTm5no/+Zi9PIHLaHipYeiIxLcos5ypn6YlcTEShxXtyyhNRXrDrK3XZ5i4qLW43NkxlbIqe0dHQ9ryL0hhYthclt41xTTtTUPL71S7K56z3jDpPgCm88ejbvBVe5/fwhNcsPupmm4aP18MTPlr11eVBSb6sIjJ68YQzbSLOV5NBhoi+F535OZ2G4Tr/aFV9KTLQbrCed1FFgvVLLUnWLqMOvru78rQ/exfNoY4S6lWktNTvqVGXJH3BNGfMm/mlTwBFLsUeiqUoyLVizD1hwYtFTSGhgJCaJ9rzRE+zNpMUmRjwuWb7Llpu+bCKBRMWNanWrl2UytRx4jj3olHejeqb3QWtvE3fp+v41ej/BraCyi4GCn4y/4+Be2dMlPEKhw8Dszu+TdNV63NMsi19xgvukpeNek+sWyevqrLH4XkXPSoPdBaZDHHCObF0wOzI5V0UBBx7ms+EzQmo41HjBDgRUzm7KCL+g8r2IIU2B3WekDpdWxEpHnl+eWKHw/4k3zWNnicOSN4uuzkD9DwBOP+9TcuyZIHa70XJLXQCS1MdHglV6l6UQJJTCIrtt3dRFJROolSb2+++VbvvKPt046iuz5gNKuWxth3SOE/YzdRghUq5Y4DkiczyZcYe5NQ0u2gQP15tkaxbu+iT6kjieBnyqc/DLpqdj+z4gzzw3JZ0nmjAWvI0kAaSYuUJjPG0nUmoRwix4kartY4ntNBYsVV1OQywPLEiPboj+Pj4GRzO0WNrF0VUKNaTOLtoLA8sZySCyprrPfh/3y3GAeax5B8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
}

#div2 {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 16958px;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>

    <div id="div2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also see it here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dewdney-hgjx3?file=/src/styles.css

I checked the larger image is valid by pasting the generated images into an base 64 viewer such as https://jaredwinick.github.io/base64-image-viewer/

How can I display the larger images and have them repeated vertically? I could use `img` elements, but I am trying not to have one `img` element per pixel. I could also paint each line over and over and make a larger image to display inside an `img` element, but the `background-image` approach would be preferable.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: A Stack Snippet `<>` in your toolbar can create the demo just as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second div shows OK on Firefox but it seems there is no standard minimum length that a browser must support.

For example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#common_problems) says:

> Length limitations
> Although Firefox supports data URLs of essentially unlimited length,
> browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of
> data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limited URLs to 65535
> characters long which limits data URLs to 65529 characters (65529
> characters being the length of the encoded data, not the source, if
> you use the plain data:, without specifying a MIME type).

I haven't found a specific definition of the length for Chrome, but it sort of looks as though it might be 16KB (16384 (edit) pixels, see comment) which seems rather small nowadays. Hopefully someone can find a definitive statement on this.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, as my image is rgba, so 4 bytes per pixel. At 16384 pixels I exceed the 65535 bytes in length..

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense as 16k bytes which I’d written seemed a bit arbitrarily small but a 64K bytes limit seems much more likely.